# Neo4j simple authentication

Tags: neo4j

I can log in using username and password here http://localhost:7474/ by typing `server: connect` and logging in. I can view data from there by executing queries.

Then I immediately switch to a new tab, or in the same tab, and go to: http://localhost:7474/db/data/, and I get:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "message" : "No authorization header supplied.",
    "code" : "Neo.ClientError.Security.AuthorizationFailed"
  } ]
}
```

And I cannot connect using py2Neo or any NEO4J libraries either using the same password; they return the exact same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

All REST API requests must now include the `Authorization` header.  To quote the [REST API Authentication and Authorization](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.1/rest-api-security.html) page of the neo4j manual:

> Requests should include an Authorization header, with a value of `Basic
>   <payload>`, where "payload" is a base64 encoded string of
>   "username:password".

That page contains some examples.

*Note: you can also disable authentication -- but you should only do this on your personal machine, for development purposes. You do this by setting to `false` the `dbms.security.auth_enabled` property in `<neo4j-install-dir>/conf/neo4j-server.properties`, and then restarting the server.*

[UPDATED]

By the way, since your question mentioned `py2neo`, you should know that its [Graph](http://py2neo.org/2.0/essentials.html#the-graph) class supports "authorisation".

Comment: What is the syntax for including the authorization header?

Comment: Follow the link in my answer for some basic info. You can also google for information on "HTTP headers" and "base64 encoding" if you are not familiar with those concepts. Finally, since your question mentioned `py2neo`, its [Graph](http://py2neo.org/2.0/essentials.html#the-graph) class supports "authorisation".

Comment: I was getting this error in Neo4j Browser, I have to hit the same query multiple times until suddenly / randomly it runs without error

Answer (score 3):

add this to your http-headers request:

Authorization: "Basic xxxx"

xxxx = base64(username:password)

Answer (score 0):

The request json should look like: (`XXX` being the Base64 encoding of the user:password string - the string to encode contains the column):

```
{
    method: "POST",
    headers: { 
        "content-type": "application/json", 
        "Authorization": "Basic XXX"
    },
    body: {
        statements:[
            {
                statement: query,
                parameters: params
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This has been tested in Javascript (axios) and in Deno.land (fetch API). ES Javascript contains a built in base64 encoding function: [btoa()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/btoa)